# Angular2 Unit Testing Services

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Unit Testing and was wondering how I would be able to approach unit testing a component that relies on one service which in turn relies on many others. Below is my initial setup.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComp],
      providers: [TestService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

But doing this, it is not able to find the other services that it relies on. Then I would provide the other services like so. But then it keep growing as those services use other services etc.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [TestComp],
          providers: [TestService, TestServiceDependencyService, TestServiceDependecyService2]
        }).compileComponents();
      }));
```

One thing I did with another unit test that relied on a service was create a mock service like so.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
    }).overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: TestService, useClass: MockTestService},
        ]
      }
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Now the mock service in here was easier because there wasn't much functionality and I  was able to "mock" the return values.

In this new component - it'd be much more difficult to mock the correct return values. What would I do in this case?

Comment: Yes, use mock services. It's unclear what the specific problem with your current component is; you don't actually show the expected behaviour or how you've tried to take it out in your tests.

Comment: What would I be mocking? It seems kind of wrong to be mocking all the services? Right now without mocking and just providing the services , I get a service.method() is not a function

Comment: *"What would I be mocking?"* - the other services the service you're testing relies on. *"It seems kind of wrong to be mocking all the services?"* - is that a question? Why does that seem wrong? The whole point is that you're isolating the behaviour of **that one service**. *"Right now..."* - then give a [mcve]. This question is too vague to be properly answerable, hence the mediocre answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is **my approach**, so don't take my word as the universal answer, but rather as a quick and easy way to do this.

First, let me tell you that for a first time, you did pretty well. You're right, **you need to mock your dependencies**.

What I do is create mock **values** instead of classes (like you did). I put them in a file, so that every mock is always the same, no matter the component you're testing.

Here is an example :

```
export const myMockedService = {};
```

As you did, you then need to provide it (the operator to import it just changes a bit) :

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [TestComp],
  providers: [{ provide: MyService, useValue: myMockedService }]
}).compileComponents();
```

Now that your service is mocked, you're good to go.

When you start testing, your component will try to call some methods of your service. Since your mock doesn't have anything, this will throw an error, saying the method is missing (let's assume  `auth()` for the sake of my example.

In this case, you simply have to add this in your mock :

```
export const myMockedService = {
  auth: () => null
};
```

And now your method is mocked ! Since you're testign a component, and not your service, you don't need to implement a complete mock, a dummy mock will do just right.

After that, you will still get some errors, such as `can't subscribe to undefined` in the case of an HTTP call.

This happens because, as you can see, the service returns **nothing**.

I think you guessed it, but here it goes anyway :

```
export const myMockedService = {
  auth: () => Observable.of(null)
};
```

Now your service returns an Observable ! In some cases, especially HTTP calls, you will need to mock the return, so that you can test what a function in your component does.

Again :

```
export const myMockedService = {
  auth: () => Observable.of(new User('Pickle', 'RIIIIIIIIIIICK'))
};
```

You now have a fully mocked auth method !

### Bonus

You can import `RouterTestingModule` and `HttpTestingModule` to mock your routing module or your http module. This will erase every error about dependencies from those 2 modules.

Comment: If you need more explanation, just ask, I'd be happy to give them to you !

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!  I think I am unsure on what I should be testing in a unit test.The stuff that I am testing is that the correct values that lies in a variable is properly displayed on the gui side, that everything updates correctly, and what should be displayed is displayed and what shouldn't be displayed is not displayed. Is my approach somewhat correct? Right now the problem with this component is that in determining what should or not be displayed relies on this service which relies on other services.In "mocking" this service,do I mock all the possible return values?

Comment: Again, **my opinion**, but I think unit tests should tests the logic of your functions. If you want to test buttons click, correct UI display and such, you should use e2e (end-to-end) testing. But you of course can do everything in your unit testing !

Answer (score -1):

As far as unit testing is concerned, you have to test only that particular component/service files any other dependencies you have to mock it and that is the way to go.